# ArcGIS - Error: This operation is not allowed while editing [Editable]

Tags: angular, arcgis, esri, arcgis-server, esri-loader

What I want to do is to create an entity, let's call it `Entity1`

```js
Enitity1 { 
  globalId: string;
}
```

And then use the `GlobalId` from the recently created `Entity1` to create `Entity2`

```js
Enitity2 {
   globalId: string;
   entity1Id: string;
}
```

This is an Angular application, and I'm using the `esri-loader` 2.14.0 and `esri-service` 2.6.0

Then I have an `esri-service-extension.ts` like this snippet:

```js
export class EsriServiceExtension {

    public static async createQuery(
      props: __esri.QueryProperties
    ): Promise<__esri.Query> {
        const [Query] = await loadModules([
          "esri/tasks/support/Query"
        ]);
        const query: __esri.Query =new Query(props);
        return query;
    }
    
}
```

And then a service where I have this:

```js
export class MyService {
    // A whole bunch of code
    
    applyEditsWithUrl = (record: any, editMode: string, url: string) => {
        let fData: FormData = new FormData;
        fData.append("f", 'json');
        fData.append("gdbVersion", "admin.Editable");
        fData.append('token', <token>);

        if (editMode === 'updates') {
            // bunch of code
        } else if (editMode === 'adds') {
            // simplified version of the code
            fData.append("adds", JSON.stringify([{"attributes": record}]));
        } else if (editMode === 'deletes') {
            // bunch of code
        }
        
        return this.httpClient.post(url, fData)
          .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
            return response;
          }))
          .pipe(catchError(error => {
            // handling of error
          }));
    }

    // A whole bunch of code
}
```

Finally, I have a component (where I use the service above) like this:

```js
export class MyComponent {
    // a whole bunch of code
    let applyEdits = this.contactsService.applyEdits(obj.entity1, "entity1", "adds"); 
    
    applyEdits.subscribe(async (response: any) => {
        // code to process the response
    }

    // a whole bunch of code

    let applyEdits = this.bulkUploadService.applyEdits(applyEdits_Adds, applyEdit_Update, applyEdits_Deletes, "entity2");

    applyEdits.subscribe(async (response: any) => {
        // code to process the response
    }
}
```

When this code is executed, the two respecte requests will look like this

```
URL: {url for entity1}/applyEdits
Status code: 200
Response: {"addResults":[{"globalId":"{GUID}","success":true}],"updateResults":[],"deleteResults":[]}
```

so this request is successful and it returns {GUID} for the Entity1 created.

```
URL: {url for entity2}/applyEdits (using {GUID} as part of the payload
Status code: 200
Response: {"error":{"code":500,"extendedCode":-2147467261,"message":"Unable to complete operation.","details":["Unable to perform applyEdits operation.","Error: This operation is not allowed while editing [Editable].  This operation is not allowed while editing [Editable]."]}}
```

My understanding of this error is: when the sencond request is sent, it appearts that {GUID} doesn't exists in Entity1 table as if the sencond request was interacting with a different version of the DB.

Does anyone know how to solve this?